# Wall Anchor - Shade sails - wind

Tags: walls, brick, anchor

This is a variation on a theme of questions that have been asked before. I have 3 shade sails and I live in Scotland... They are anchored into two 6 inch posts, and the wall of the house. They have shock reducing springs to take the grunt out of the wind when it gusts, but they are not typically left out in the bad weather. The wall side of the sails are anchored using M6 stainless wall anchors, into the brick and harled/pebbledash wall. It's a modern house with modern style concrete bricks.

The wall anchors have a lifting eye nuts on them locked against the wall anchor nuts, I simply clip the sails in using 6mm stainless clips.

The load is not purely longitudinal, but the angle is only ~30 degrees off, for rain shedding. The shade sails obviously are under tension when they are up. I had thought this would be man enough for the task and I cranked the anchors up quite tight, but worried about splitting the brick, so I didn't go daft.

I just took them down and noticed that the wall anchors have a bit of movement in them. At this point I'm assuming the shock loading in the wind has caused the anchor face inside the brick to break down. So I was pondering what glues I might use to consolidate the anchor and avoid any failures. I haven't tried simply tightening them yet, I know this will work in the short term but it seems I have an issue beyond the bolt coming loose, as the load eye and the nut on the anchor bolt are locked against each other. I'd lay odds that nut hasn't moved...

Having read some comments in the group I noted folks saying that such anchors shouldn't be used for non-sheer loads. Do I have a fundamental issue here? What would the wisdom of the group recommend in this case? Replace the straight eye on the bolt with some kind of plate to ensure the load is more transverse? How do the commercial eyes you see work?

The installation works well, I'm just concerned these anchors are going to pull out and take the pebbledash with them.

Advice sought...

Comment: Some pictures of the problem would help a lot...

Comment: And what is the construction like on the other side of the wall?

Comment: So these are wedge anchors that you've installed into brick? Or a mortar joint? I had to look up "harled," where my understanding is that it obscures the brick's joints. How far into the brick is the anchor embedded? The nut+washer bear directly on the harled surface? You've fastened an M6 eye nut to the extra threads sticking out beyond the nut?

Comment: Are these 2-1/4 inch tall by 4" deep by 7-5/8" inch long standard bricks (57mm tall x 102mm deep x 194 mm long) like in the US? Or something larger?

Comment: While others are answering the nuts and bolts, I would like to inform you about `Motorized retractable sails`, controlled by wind sensor. I have an awning like that, and it works great when suddenly there is wind, or I am not home to close it. There are multiple products on the market so look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Those anchors move over time and become loose.

So, a loop welded to a plate would be better with 4 fixings on the pkate held in with resin spread over 2 or 4 bricks.

Answer (score 0):

If the three sails are in a row along the same wall, an efficient way to mount them all would be to mount a long perforated square steel tube (perhaps painted to match the wall or the sail) to the entire length of the wall using a large number of bolts.  This will spread the load and the face of the tube pressed against the wall will reduce or eliminate the transverse forces that are jiggling your anchors loose.  Then mount each sail to the tubing.

Answer (score 0):

You installed a wedge anchor into a mortar joint or at least close to a mortar joint. This is the weakest location to install such anchors. [Sleeve anchors](https://www.grainger.com/product/MKT-FASTENING-Sleeve-Anchor-2-1-4-in-Overall-30PK64) were invented for cases like brick mortar joints. You want to use [D-ring tie downs](https://www.uscargocontrol.com/products/mounting-ring-1-x-800-lbs-stainless-steel-t316) with two sleeve anchors each. You could install these sleeve anchors above and below the old anchor to obscure its scar. If you can get the old anchor out, then you could reuse its hole with a sleeve anchor. Anchoring in the brick will be stronger than anchoring in the mortar, so anchoring in the brick is preferred from a strength standpoint.

[image: Sleeve anchor]
[image: D-ring-tie down]